# How to use math symbols to represent a basic formula

Tags: notation, summation

I've a fomula that looks like this:

How to properly represent this formula using SUM Symbol and MEAN symbol?
$$
    r=2 \left(3(f_1) +\frac{(g_1+...+ g_n)}{n} + \frac{s_1 +... + s_n}{n}\right) + x_1 + y_1
$$

I don't know how to represent this in math symbols. 
I know that the hole form is a sum and i also know that i'm calculating the mean whem i perform a sum of n numbers and i divide it by n.

Comment: You divide the sum of **two** elements only, seemingly, twice. Or, did you mean $g_1+g_2+g_3+\dots+g_n$ instead of '(g1 + gN)'?

Comment: yeah you get it right: i mean g1+g2+g3+⋯+gn

Comment: Is the N in `gN` supposed to be the same as the `n` in the denominator?  So that `(g1 + … + gN)/n` is the mean of the g's?

Comment: yes. you were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{(g_1+...+g_N)}{n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_i}{n}
$$
$$
\frac{(s_1+...+s_N)}{n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i}{n}
$$
so,

$$
r=2\left(3(f_1)+2 \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_i}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i}{n}\right)\right)+x_1+y_1
$$

Comment: it seems to me that it have some mistakes. Doesn't it? 
((3 * f1) + (2* ( (g1 + … + gN) / n) + ((s1 + … + sN) / n)) * 2
the hole formula is multiplied by 2 which is not represented above.

(2* ( (g1 + … + gN) / n) -> this is multiplied by 2
((s1 + … + sN) / n))  -> this is NOT multiplied by 2. That's just a mean.

Comment: Yes. It's correct. Thank you very much Felipe

Answer (score 1):

The *mean* of some elements $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n$ is often denoted by $\bar g$, you can *introduce* it by a sum notation.
$$\bar g:=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^ng_k}n=\frac{g_1+g_2+\dots+g_n}n\,.$$

Comment: what does the k=1 actually mean? does it means that he will have at least on g1?

Comment: $k$ is a "dummy" variable, like a loop index in programming, going from 1 to $n$.

Comment: ah ok. But how can i integrate the hole formula? Because i don't have math background and what confuses me is the way we represent those operations